# Material UI Picker: Opening KeyboardDatePicker on focus

Tags: material-ui

We usually need to Click on the Calendar icon to open, I want to know a way to open the DialogBox whenever someone clicks on the input

Comment: You should try this: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker

Comment: I actually needed the dialog box only therefore I am searching for answers